# MySQL upgrade don't work in other server

Tags: magento-1.9, database, setup-upgrade

I have a problem with a upgrade of a custom module.

In my local environment work fine, but when I upload this changes to the server, i have all changes in the server except the new version of module.

I try delete the module in the database in the table core_resource for force upgrade but don't work.

This is my config of versions:

```
<Company_Module>
        <!-- <version>1.0.0</version> // just in QA -->
        <!-- <version>1.0.1</version> // just in QA -->
        <!-- <version>1.0.2</version> // just in QA -->
        <!-- <version>1.0.3</version> // add introduction text and closing text -->
        <!-- <version>1.0.4</version> // added Postal, Region City to settings -->
        <version>1.0.5</version> <!-- added Margin in quotation_line --> 
</Company_Module>
```

Now the module never appear in the table core_resource.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Remove entry from core_resource. Try to clear cache. And logout and login . Install module again. Clear cache  login and logout . Make sure you are working on same database you configured in Magento.

Comment: Thank you Chirag, but i try this. I'm speaking with my team of infrastructure because we have a load balancer with 3 servers. I clean cache in 1 server because to other servers i can't access. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Yes That may cause issue.